# NameError: undefined local variable or method `digest' for #<User:0xe9d3d58>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, railstutorial.org

My user.rb file consists of

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

   # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    return false if digest.nil?**
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end
end
```

User_test.rb [65 -67 lines] are:

```
    test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
    assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
end
```

I get the errors

> test_authenticated?_should_return_false_for_a_user_with_nil_digest#UserTest
>   (0.84s) NameError: undefined local variable or method `digest' for
>
> ```
>         app/models/user.rb:37:in `authenticated?'
>         test/models/user_test.rb:66:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`digest` is a class method and it is called in an instance method.

Change your `authenticated` method to

```
def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?**
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(token)
  end
```

or change your `digest` method to

```
 def digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
```

Comment: The problem is that this code is from the https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out, so I dont think there are any mistakes

Comment: But there is no attribute or method that is called `digest` in the user mode. Rather it is called `remember_digest` so you should change `if digest.nil?**` to `if remember_digest.nil?` and change it in the `BCrypt::Password.new` to `remember_digest` too

Comment: I've tried  to do as in the answer from this question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804660/nameerror-undefined-local-variable-or-method-remember-digest-and-nomethoderror), but it didn't help

Comment: Check Listing 8.33 in the book you refrenced and change your `digest` to `remember_digest`. Also remember to migrate.

Comment: Listing 8.45: Updating authenticated? to handle a nonexistent digest. green

Comment: return false if remember_digest.nil? - it work's! Thank's for your help

Comment: Yes your only problem is that you check if `digest.nil?` just change the word `digest` to `remember_digest` it is the name of the column!